# Power Query conditional sumif

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I need to add a column that Sums the value column of all columns that have a common id. However, any id = null is not summed, but equal to the value column.

[image]

The above example should result in:

```
TopPaymendId                            JournalLineNetAmount    TopAmount
fcbcd407-ca26-4ea0-839a-c39767d05403    -3623.98                -7061.23
fcbcd407-ca26-4ea0-839a-c39767d05403    -3437.25                -7061.23
ce77faac-1638-40e9-ad62-be1813ce9031    -88.68                  -88.68
531d9bde-3f52-47f3-a9cf-6f3566733af2    -152.23                 -152.23
8266dfef-dd14-4654-a6d2-091729defde7    229.42                  229.42
f8b97a47-15ef-427d-95e0-ce23cc8efb1f    -777                    -777
                                null    -3.01                   -3.01
                                null    -2.94                   -2.94
                                null    3312.5                  3312.5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code should work:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Data"]}[Content],
    group = Table.Group(Source, {"TopPaymendId"}, {"TopAmount", each List.Sum([JournalLineNetAmount])}),
    join = Table.Join(Source,{"TopPaymendId"},group,{"TopPaymendId"}),
    replace = Table.ReplaceValue(join,each [TopAmount],each if [TopPaymendId] = null 
              then [JournalLineNetAmount] else [TopAmount],Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"TopAmount"})
in
    replace
```

[image]